# Find the distribution from a game

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have been thinking on the following problem during the weekend and I have no idea where to begin.

A player plays the following game: at each step of the game, he can double or divide his portfolio with a probability of $\frac{1- p }{2}$ or lose everything with probability $p$, for $p \in (0, 1)$.

The player's starting wallet is $1$ dollar. Let $X_n$ represent the state of the portfolio after $n$ steps, find:

The distribution of $X_n$ and the possible value of it, $~ \lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n = 0)$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} E(X_n = 0)$.

Comment: If he divides his portfolio, what does he divide it by?  Note that the value only depends on how many of each step have happened, not the order they happen in.

Comment: @RossMillikan it will be divided by $2$. Yes for sure, it $X_n$ depends at the end by the actions happened what ever its order but how to gather this as a probability!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compute the probability of halving each number of steps.  For example, if there is ever a lose everything, the value is zero.  The chance of having at least one lose everything after $n$ steps is $1-(1-p)^n$.  Now if you assume you didn't lose everything, you have a $\frac 12$ chance at each step to double or cut in half.  If you have $k$ doubles you have a final portfolio of $2^k\cdot \frac 1{2^{n-k}}=2^{2k-n}$  The final distribution is 
$$\begin {array} {r r}\text{value}&\text{probability}\\
0&1-(1-p)^n\\
2^{2k-n}&(1-p)^n{n \choose k}2^{-n}
\end {array}$$
for $0 \le k \le n$

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for late reply. In fact, I didn't reply though the previous week because I've been trying to think and to understand the answer. Unfortunately, I still have difficulties! Why the chance of having at least one lose everything after $n$ steps is $1-(1-p)^n$. Why the portfolio equals $2^{2k-n}$ if there are $k$ doubles.

Comment: If you hit lose everything once, you are done.  The chance you don't lose everything on one step is $(1-p)$.  For $n$ plays, the chance you never lose everything is $(1-p)^n$, so the chance you lose everything at least once is $1-(1-p)^n$.  If there are $k$ doubles there are $n-k$ halves and you just multiply those together.

Comment: Yes but how does multiplying them equal $2^k \frac{1}{2^{n-k}}$?

Comment: $k$ doublings results in multiplying by $2^k$.  $n-k$ halvings results in multiplying by $\left(\frac 12\right)^{n-k}=\frac 1{2^{n-k}}=2^{k-n}$.  Doing both is the product of these.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I totally forgot that we start with $1$ dollar!

Comment: @RossMillikan I think the second probability equals $(1-p)^n \binom{n}{k}\bigl( \frac{1}{2}\bigr)^{k}$ not $(1-p)^n \binom{n}{k}\bigl( \frac{1}{2}\bigr)^{n}$, isn't it ?

Comment: No, you have $n$ coin flips, none of which is lose everything, so the chance of double or half is $\frac 12$